# aria-expanded on the button that gets removed from DOM

Tags: javascript, html, angular, accessibility, toggle

There is a link... no, here is a button....

```
<button *ngIf="!isExpanded" aria-expanded="false">Expand</button>
```

that executes some javascript code to expand some area.

How properly we should deal with the case when this link gets removed from DOM upon link click, because *ngIf="!isExpanded" become *false*? As result, aria-expanded="true" won't come into play in this case.  How to tell the aria-expanded became true?

Comment: what do you mean with (this link gets removed from DOM upon link click?) can you explain more so i could help you

Comment: *ngIf="!isExpanded"  removes this link from DOM

Comment: If you want to talk about accessibility you should talk about semantics such as as not using an anchor out of its scope (directing to another file/resource)

Comment: Thank you, upgraded to a button, not a link now.

Comment: Removing an element is dangerous in terms of lost focus and not aligned with any convention. If collapsing the element should not be possible after, maybe `disabled` would be an option? Otherwise, the button should not use the `aria-expanded` attribute, put focus on the expanded contents after click before it gets deleted.

Comment: @Andy, Interesting...  Thank you very much... Let's wait to see hopefully any more answers... or, that's the only more or less good option...

Comment: In general, making a UX accessible is not too hard, but making a confusing UX accessible is extremely hard. If the interaction model doesn't make sense for a sighted mouse user, then it's hard to convey what is happening to a screen reader user. Rather than try to solve how to mark a button as expanded and deleting the button, time should be spent on thinking about the UX itself.

Comment: Both @(andy and quentinc) are experienced accessibility people and all 3 of us have said the same thing.

Comment: What’s the actual use case here? I remember that I answered to a similar question where the button would reveal a spoiler. The spoiler would be rendered blurry, and should be hidden from screen readers, until revealed by a button. This would be a one-time action and actually makes sense to me. It’s even a quite established interaction pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the button from the DOM once it has been clicked is a bad idea.

You have no reliable way to communicate the expanded state. Even though you set aria-expanded to true, the screen reader might not have the time to properly announce it before the button is removed, or the announcement might be cut in the middle.
So maybe it won't always be clear on what exactly happened upon click.

Additionally, if you remove the currently focused element, the focus is basically going nowhere or at a random place.
It can be a real problem for keyboard only users, since the focus might not be recoverable without a mouse.

There's also another question: what if I want to collapse the section again ?
It could be very useful to do so and especially if the section is long. For screen reader and keyboard only users, it can save a lot of tabs and/or up/down arrows, in several different cases: when I have finished reading / working with the section, when the section don't show what I wanted, etc.
Is there a particular reason that let you think that it's totally useless to collapse the section once it's expanded ?

UX speaking, unless if you really have a good reason or the action is obviously definitive, there should always be a way to cancel / go back to a previous state.
Expanding/collapsing a section is of course completely harmful compared to deleting data or sending a paiement, but still, as explained above you can make some people waste time. Here you don't have any good reason to prevent it, so you should probably allow it.

So at least for the above reasons, I would recommend you to not remove that button when it's clicked.
For partially sighted users using a screen magnifier, it's also a bad idea to move it far away, because they can easily lose track of where it went.